# How to get property value of JSON Tree Schema using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a JSON Tree structure like this.

```
[
  {
    "title": "Blogs",
    "id": "blogs",
    "type": "array",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Today",
        "id": "today",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "title": "Yesterday",
        "id": "yesterday",
        "type": "enum",
        "options": [
          "Y1",
          "Y2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Links",
    "id": "links",
    "type": "object",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Oracle",
        "id": "oracle",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "USA",
            "id": "usa",
            "type": "array",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "Midwest",
                "id": "midwest",
                "type": "enum",
                "options": [
                  "Md1",
                  "Md2"
                ]
              },
              {
                "title": "West",
                "id": "west",
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "Asia",
            "id": "asia",
            "type": "array",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "India",
                "id": "india",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want a recursive function which takes 2 arguments(1st argument is The actual Tree Data and 2nd argument is a path with dot notation) and returns the type of the node (string/object/array/boolean) and enum values if the type is enum. The dot notation path may contain the array index as 0 or 1 or so on.
Basically what i want is

```
var nodeType = getType(treeData, 'links.oracle.usa.0.midwest');  // Note: there is a 0 as usa is an array type
console.log(nodeType); // Should return [{"type":"enum"},{"options": ["md1", "md2"]}]

var nodeType = getType(treeData, 'blogs.0.today');
console.log(nodeType); // Should return [{"type":"string"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like working code, which handles wrong paths as well:

```js
const sample = [
  {
    "title": "Blogs",
    "id": "blogs",
    "type": "array",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Today",
        "id": "today",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "title": "Yesterday",
        "id": "yesterday",
        "type": "enum",
        "options": [
          "Y1",
          "Y2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Links",
    "id": "links",
    "type": "object",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Oracle",
        "id": "oracle",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "USA",
            "id": "usa",
            "type": "array",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "Midwest",
                "id": "midwest",
                "type": "enum",
                "options": [
                  "Md1",
                  "Md2"
                ]
              },
              {
                "title": "West",
                "id": "west",
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "Asia",
            "id": "asia",
            "type": "array",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "India",
                "id": "india",
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const getType = (tree, path) => {
  if (!path.length) return

  const element = getElementFromTree(tree, path.split('.'))
  if (!element || !element.type) return

  const res = [{ type: element.type }]
  if (element.options) {
    res.push({ options: element.options })
  }
  return res
}

const getElementFromTree = (treePart, path) => {
  const prop = path.shift()
  if (!path.length) {
    return treePart.id === prop ? treePart : undefined
  }

  let nextTreePart;
  if (Array.isArray(treePart)) {
    nextTreePart = treePart.find(v => v.id === prop)
  } else if (isNaN(prop)) {
    nextTreePart = treePart.children.find(v => v.id === prop)
  } else {
    nextTreePart = treePart.children[prop]
  }

  if (!nextTreePart) return
  if (path.length) {
    return getElementFromTree(nextTreePart, path)
  }
  return nextTreePart
}

// work as expected:
console.log(getType(sample, 'links.oracle.usa.0.midwest'))
console.log(getType(sample, 'links.oracle.usa.1.west'))
console.log(getType(sample, 'blogs.0.today'))
console.log(getType(sample, 'blogs.1.yesterday'))
console.log(getType(sample, 'links.oracle.asia.0.india'))

// tests with wrong paths, all return undefined
console.log(getType(sample, 'links.oracle.usa.5.west')) // because 5th element doesn't exists
console.log(getType(sample, 'blogs.3.today')) // because 3rd element doesn't exists
console.log(getType(sample, 'links.oracle')) // because links.oracle doesn't contain type field in it
console.log(getType(sample, '10.this.is.wrong.path')) // because path doesn't exist at all
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks @Max for the solution but I need to specify the last node after the index. Because in my form the user can click Add button for the array elements. So the Tree will have an Id called 0 or 1 and so on. Hence i need to specify the full path i.e blog.0.today

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to break this into a few functions.  The tree-searching code starts with a path like `["links", "oracle", "usa", "midwest"]` and a data object with a `children` array property, returning the node at that path, or `undefined` if it doesn't exist.

Then we write a simple wrapper to convert your `"links.oracle.usa.0.midwest"` string into that array and to wrap your input array into the `children` property of a new object.  This `getNode` function also returns the node or `undefined`.  It is an independently useful function.

Then because you eventually want the node type, we add the simple wrapper `getType` to report on the node's type or `"unknown"` if it's not found.  We could easily replace `"unknown"` with `undefined` or whatever you choose in an obvious manner.

```js
const findInTree = (xs) => ([p = undefined, ...ps]) =>
  xs == undefined 
    ? undefined
  : p == undefined
    ? xs
  : findInTree (xs .children .find (({id}) => id == p)) (ps)

const getNode = (xs) => (path) =>
  findInTree ({children: xs}) (path .split ('.') .filter (isNaN))

const getType = (xs) => (path) =>
  (getNode (xs) (path) || {type: 'unknown'}) .type

const data = [{title: "Blogs", id: "blogs", type: "array", children: [{title: "Today", id: "today", type: "string"}, {title: "Yesterday", id: "yesterday", type: "enum", options: ["Y1", "Y2"]}]}, {title: "Links", id: "links", type: "object", children: [{title: "Oracle", id: "oracle", children: [{title: "USA", id: "usa", type: "array", children: [{title: "Midwest", id: "midwest", type: "enum", options: ["Md1", "Md2"]}, {title: "West", id: "west", type: "boolean"}]}, {title: "Asia", id: "asia", type: "array", children: [{title: "India", id: "india", type: "string"}]}]}]}];

console .log (getType (data) ("links.oracle.usa.0.midwest")) //~> "enum"
console .log (getType (data) ("links.oracle.usa"))           //~> "array"
console .log (getType (data) ("blogs.0.today"))              //~> "string"
console .log (getType (data) ("blogs.2.tomorrow"))           //~> "unknown"
```

These functions are all fairly simple.  The recursion is clear; the breakdown of responsibilities should be straightforward.

But I had to make an assumption here.  As pointed out in another answer, the array index and the following id are redundant.  We could add complexity to the recursive function to deal with this case, but that would make for ugly code.  Instead, before processing the node, we remove the array index.  That's what the `.filter (isNaN)` is for in `getNode`.  If this is not the desired behavior, if, for instance, you would want to fail or return `undefined` if the index and the id didn't match, then we'd have to do something pretty different.  I didn't really follow your rationale for needed the index and the id, but in a comment on another answer you seem to imply that it's the id you really need.  If it's both, then this technique would need heavy -- and ugly -- modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lodash `get` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) it allows for: `_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');`. It is safe regarding getting value from non existing path - wont throw error.

Comment: Thank you. But the project is not built on top of NodeJs. Is there any other conventional way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use this npm package: [npmjs.com/package/lodash.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get)

Comment: You can provide an optional third argument that specifies the default value.

Comment: @SaktiDash, as previous comment suggests - Lodash is widely used in web applcations. Install with npm/yarn or append lodash script via CDN directly to your HTML https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/

Comment: Thanks @Brad !!  How to take the id into this get method? my Json is a schema structure. Could you help. So a[0], b , c will be values and key will be "id" in my case.

Comment: @BRad !! Do i need to use filter for this case?